# Reclaim Space After failed Catalina Download

Tags: macos, catalina

I tried to download Catalina and it failed after a network error. I deleted the installer in Applications. Before I deleted the installer, I had 10+gb free space. Now I have 5+gb free space and it is preventing me from downloading Catalina afresh given that I have no space. When I opened Catalina installer before I deleted it, it was not up to the 4+gb I had downloaded before the error. Where did my space go?

Comment: 10GB is *nowhere near* enough free space on any drive. You really really need more, 15% minimum, more if it's only a tiny drive, 128/256. Then the rest will just work itself out.

Comment: You are right. I deleted and reclaimed more space and catalina started from where it stopped. I guess it took up some space in system because I noticed system increased. Thanks. Should I delete the question?